# Updating a model attribute

Tags: backbone.js

I am practising Backbone js. I have a collection consisting of 10 models. In just one model, I want to change 2 of the attributes. I am using the device local storage. I have tried the following code (this is just part of the larger script):

```
this.collection.forEach(function(user) {
                    if (user.get('subject') === 'Physics') {
                        user.set({'title': 'hdrodynamics'});
                        user.save();
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
                        return;
                    }
                });
```

I consider this method inefficient. What happens as the collection length increases. I believe there is a better way than this.

Comment: Why do you consider this inefficient? What better way do you ave in mind? How are you sorting the collection? Can you get direct access to the changed model via your application UI? If not why? Please add more details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [collection.findWhere](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere), which:

> directly returns only the first model in the collection that matches the passed attributes.

Which can reduce the number of iterations run.

You can also use [model.save with attributes](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) to avoid doing the extra 'set'.

```js
// Stops when matching model is found
var physicsModel = this.collection.findWhere({ subject: 'Physics' });
// might want to do some null-checking...
// Performs a set prior to POSTing, firing correct 'change' events
physicsModel.save({ title: 'hydrodynamics' });
```

Note: A more efficient way to do this would be to avoid the lookup in the collection. For example, if this model should 'save' by some action from the user, you could leverage the model's view to gain access to the correct model (i.e. `this.model.save()`). This of course is implementation dependent.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion successfully. It is better than my method